# Counter example of upper semicontinuity of global fiber dimension on the source

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

We know that if $f : X\to Y$ is a morphism between two affine varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$, then the function that assigns to each point of $X$ the dimension of the fiber it belongs to is upper semicontinuous on $X$.

Does anyone know of a simple counterexample when $X$ is not irreducible (but remains an algebraic set over $k$, i.e a finitely generated $k$-algebra) to the global statement?

Edit: to avoid ambiguity I am looking for a counterexample in case $X$ is not irreducible when the dimension of the fibers is measured globally, i.e. $n\geq 0$, the set of $x\in X$ such that $\dim(f^{-1}(f(x) ) ) \geq n$ is closed in $X$.

Edit2: in his comments @dorebell linked an answer here https://mathoverflow.net/a/184925/3333 where a counterexample to the upper semicontinuity of global dimension on the source is given with $X$ and $Y$ affine and irreducible (it works even if the counterexample is explained looking at the dimension of fibers from the target)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I recently found it while reading about this problem. 

Be careful: in fact, the statement you give is not true even for $X$ irreducible when $X,Y$ are no longer supposed to be affine (and possibly when they are?) This answer gives a counterexample: http://mathoverflow.net/a/184925/56878

Comment: @dorebell yes you are right. Thank you for your link. It is hopefully true as I stated it with the irreducibility and affine hypothesis.

Comment: I'd love to see a proof/reference if you have one easily available! This would be a very convenient form of the result.

Comment: @dorebell look at 14.8 in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra for instance

Comment: @dorebell You can also find detailed discussion in exercises 10.5 and 10.6 of Kemper's Course in Commutative Algebra

Comment: @dorebell I just realize that even with the references I gave you the result is not completely obvious. I proved it the following way : using irreducibility of X and Y, you can apply the corollary 14.6 of Eisenbud to get it for $n=dim\ Y-dim\ X$ on an open set $U$ of $Y$. Outside of it, the irreducible components of $Y-U$ are of dimension < $dim\ Y$. A simple recurrence on $dim\ Y$ then works well.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm missing something. Isn't is possible that if $Z$ is an irreducible component of $Y - U$, then $f^{-1}(Z)$ is not irreducible? In this case, I don't see how the recurrence goes through.

Comment: @dorebell Usually $f^{-1}(Z)$ is not irreducible. Let $(W_i)$ be its irreducible components. Consider the restriction $f_i$ of $f$ to $W_i\to Z$. By the recurrence hypothesis $\{x\in W_i \mid dim\ f_i^{-1}(f_i(x))\geq n\}$ is closed. Then the union of all such sets finishes the recurrence step.

Comment: @dorebell Is everything clear for you now ?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see it. With this argument, the irreducibility hypothesis on $X$ would be unnecessary. The problem I see is that the Union of the sets you mentioned is not the set of all points such that $\dim f^{-1}(f(x)) \geq n$. There could be points in $W_i \setminus W_j$ whose $f_i$ fiber has dimension less than $n$, but which are in the same fiber as points in $W_j$ with $f_j$ fiber dimension greater than or equal to $n$: this is exactly the sort of thing that happens in the answers to this question and the linked one.

Comment: I think you need to replace $\dim f^{-1}(f(x))$ with  $\dim_x f^{-1}(f(x))$ as in the linked question. I don't think the argument is using special global properties of affine varieties anywhere, so it should work the same way for non-affine varieties.

Comment: @dorebell I see your point. I need to get back to my thinking of that time (the explanation I gave was made up  quickly (and wrongly) to answer you). Perhaps I was wrong but clearly I did not have in mind the $\text{dim}_x f^{-1}(f(x))$ result which is exactly theorem 14.8.a) of Eisenbud. Please, allow me some time. Thanks!

Comment: No problem - I'd love to hear what you figure out.

Comment: @dorebell I can say now that you are right (but me too): the statement I made was correct (the dimension here is measured locally) but the edit was about the global dimension for which I was looking for a counterexample! The proof I gave you was also right but only for local dimension statement obviously as you noticed (the more general statement is wrong as the example in your link showed) so I forgot the $x$ index in the dimension in the $W_i$.

Comment: @dorebell Because of your comments (+1 to all of them), I have edited my question to get rid of the unnecessary irreducibility hypothesis in the general statement, and add the link you suggested. Thanks again and sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: I'm glad we're on the same page now! This problem turned out to be unexpectedly subtle.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $X = (\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{x = 0\}) \coprod \mathbb{A}^1$, let $Y = \mathbb{A}^1$, and let $f$ be projection onto the first coordinate on the first component and the identity on the second. Then every point of $X$ lives in a one-dimensional fiber except the origin of the second component.

Comment: @EvanJenkins Thank you for your answer, but there are things I do not understand. First of all, how can you make X into an algebraic set (i.e. the Spec of a finitely generated algebra) ? It seems to me you cannot because of the plane minus a point. Second, the fiber to which belongs the origin of the second component is $0\amalg (\mathbb{A}^1-0)$ which is one dimensional right ? 

Comment: @brunoh: It's not a plane minus a point, it's a plane minus a line, which answers both your questions.

Comment: @brunoh: Evan isn't removing just a point from $\mathbb A^2$ but the whole line $\{x=0\}$.  I think this clarifies both of the points you raised.

Comment: Hi, I'm still not sure why this is not semicontinuous in the sense of the original question.

Consider $n = 1$.  Then the set of points *of $X$* who live in fibers of  dimension is $\geq 1$ is just `$\mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{x = 0\}$`.  This is closed in $X$.  The set of points of $X$ who live in fibers of dimension $\geq 0$ is all of $X$ of course.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, the set of points of $X$ which live in a positive dimensional fiber is $\mathbb A^2 \setminus \{x=0\} \sqcup \mathbb A^1 \setminus \{0\}$, which is not closed in $\mathbb A^2 \setminus \{x=0\} \sqcup \mathbb A^1$.

Comment: Ah, of course, sorry about that.

Comment: @Dan Thank you ver much for your explanations ! I misread the answer. Without the line it works fine. I got my answer and upvoted both your explanations.

Comment: @EvenJenkins Is there a counterexample in which X is irreducible?

Answer (score 4):

For what its worth, I can give you a non-Noetherian example, even with both schemes affine, irreducible (and of finite Krull dimension).

Set $R = k[x,y,x/y, x/y^2, x/y^3, ...]$ and $S = k[y]$.  We have the obvious map $S \hookrightarrow R$ which induces
$$
X = \text{Spec }R \to Y = \text{Spec }S.
$$
Now, away from the origin of $S$, $y$ is invertible and $R[y^{-1}] = k[x,y,y^{-1}]$ has all fibers with dimension $1$.  On the other hand, once we set $y = 0$ in $R$, we notice that $x = (x/y) y$ is a multiple, as is $(x/y) = (x/y^2) y$, and so is $(x/y^n)$ for all $n$.  This is already a maximal ideal, so the fiber over $y = 0$ is $0$-dimensional.

Comment: @Karl First of all, thank you very much for taking the time to notice it was probably not an obvious question. I like very much your example also and upvoted it. Nevertheless I cannot consider it as an the counter example I was looking for, because of the non-noetherianness of $X$. Since the result on the upper semicontinuity of fiber dimension is based on the the Generic Freeness Lemma, a key hypothesis is finite generation of the algebra involved, right ? That is why I need a counterexample using algebraic sets (SpecMax of finitely generated algebra over $k$).

Comment: I agree, it doesn't answer your question but I still thought it was amusing.

Comment: The origin in closed in $X$, is it not?

Answer (score 2):

Let $ X = \mathbb A^2 \cup pt$, let $Y = \mathbb P^1$. Let $f(\mathbb A^2) = \mathbb A^1$ by projection, and let $f(pt)=\infty$. Then the generic fiber dimension is $1$, but at one point the fiber dimension is $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your your answer. But first of all, I wanted a counterexample using only affine varieties, not projective ones. Second, I fail to see why it is a counterexample, since the dimension function is still upper semicontinuous on $X$, right ?

Comment: It is not upper semicontinuous because the fiber dimension at infinity is $0$, but on any neighborhood of $0$ all other fibers are $1$-dimensional. The dimension function is actually lower semicontinuous here.

Comment: Yes, good point. To solve this, connect the point to $\mathbb A^2$ using a line.

Comment: Let $Y$ be irreducible of positive dimension, and $p$ a point in $Y$. Let `$X = ((Y\setminus p) \times {\mathbb A}^1) \coprod \{q\}$`, and $X\to Y$ be projection on the first component, and $q\mapsto p$ on the second.

Comment: But where are you mapping that point to? Y must be affine, right?

Comment: @Allen_Knutson It seems to me the dimension function is still upper semicontinuous. I also found this counterexample but realized my mistake. I think to find a counterexample one has to find fibers in $X$ with irreducible components of different dimensions each one of them staying in different irreducible components of $X$. I failed to do that yet ...