# A question on dominant morphism of affine schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, dimension-theory

Let $A \subseteq B$ be a ring extension where $A,B$ are both finitely generated $\mathbb C$-domain of the same Krull dimension. Also assume $A$ is regular (i.e. $A_{ \mathfrak p}$ is regular local ring for every prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ of $A$ ).

If $P$ is a prime ideal of $A$ with finitely many prime ideals of $B$ lying over it  , then does there exist $f \in A \setminus P$ such that every prime ideal of $A_f$ has finitely many prime ideals of $B$ lying over it ?

Comment: I am not able to understand where is the dominant morphism of Affine schemes...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: just the inclusion $A \to B$ ...

Comment: Do you think title can be edited to make it clearer or it is difficult to say this in one line.. I am not questioning anything I am simply asking.. Can you tell how does algebraic geometry tag is relevant here?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: In algebraic geometric terms ... let $X,Y$ be integral, finite type, affine $\mathbb C$-schemes with $\dim X=\dim Y$ with $Y$ non-singular, normal. Let $f: X \to Y$ be a dominant morphism. Let $U:=\{y\in Y : f^{-1}(\{y\}) $ is finite and non-empty $\}$ . Question: Is $U$ open ?

Comment: I am sorry that I am only asking you to do something but not answering your question. I simply do not know how to answer. Algebraic geometry version looks interesting. Thanks.

Comment: This is a duplicate from [https://mathoverflow.net/questions/193/when-is-fiber-dimension-upper-semi-continuous]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comment of @MatthieuRomagny gives a link to some positive answers under additional hypotheses.  Nonetheless, the answer is negative without further hypotheses. Before stating the negative counterexamples, let me state the positive result (that I suspect motivated this question).

**Zariski's Main Theorem (Original Form).** A birational (separated, finite type) morphism to a normal (finite type) $k$-scheme restricts as an open immersion on the maximal open of the domain where the morphism is quasi-finite.

One excellent reference for Zariski's Main Theorem is Section III.9 of the following (the formulation above is on p. 288).

MR0971985 (89k:14001) 
Mumford, David 
The red book of varieties and schemes. 
 
Lecture Notes in Mathematics, 1358. 
Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1988.

**Corollary of ZMT.** For a birational (separated, finite type) morphism to a normal (finite type) $k$-scheme, for every point of the target where the fiber is nonempty and finite, there exists an open neighborhood of the point over which the morphism is an isomorphism.

**Counterexamples.** Nonetheless, if you remove the hypothesis that the morphism is birational, there are counterexamples.  Here is one.

Let $k$ be a field, and let $A$ be the polynomial ring $k[s,t,u]$.  Let $B$ be the ring $k[x,y,z,w]/\langle zw-1 \rangle$.  Both of these are finitely generated $k$-algebras that are regular, in fact $k$-smooth.  Now consider the $k$-algebra homomorphism, $$p:A\to B, \ \ p(s) = x(1-x), \ p(t) = xy, \ p(u) = z(1-xz).$$  If we invert the element $s$ in $A$ and the image element $x(1-x)$ in $B$, then the induced ring homomorphism is finite and flat of rank $4$.  In particular, the localized ring homomorphism is injective.  Since the natural map from $A$ to $A[1/s]$ is injective, also $p$ is injective.

Finally, consider the prime ideal $P=\langle s,t,u\rangle$ in $A$.  There is precisely one prime lying above this prime, namely $\langle x-1,y,z-1,w-1\rangle$.  However, the prime ideal $Q=\langle s,t \rangle$ has infinitely many primes lying over it, e.g., $\langle x,q(y) \rangle$ where $q(y)\in k[y]$ is an arbitrary nonzero, noninvertible element that is irreducible.  Since $Q$ is contained in $P$, for every $f\in A\setminus P$, also $f$ is in $A\setminus Q$.  Thus, the ideal $QA_f$ is a prime ideal of $A_f$.  So the induced ring homomorphism $A_f \to B_{p(f)}$ still admits a prime ideal $QA_f$ that has infinitely many primes lying over it in $B_{p(f)}$.

There are also counterexamples to the corollary if we allow that the fiber is empty (but the morphism is still birational).  Namely, consider the self-map, $$r:A\to A, \ \ r(s) = s, \ r(t) = st, \ r(u) = 1-su.$$  This ring homomorphism is birational.  The fiber over $\langle s,t,u\rangle$ is empty.  Yet the fiber over $\langle s,t \rangle$ is infinite, as above.